# I think I accidentally erased Macintosh HD?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, partition, install

I was trying to install OS X on my Mac that had OS X removed. I wrongly erased Macintosh HD and it changed to "Untitled". After that I restarted my Mac and it just shows an image of "?" in a folder.  I'm only able to use Internet Recovery (after holding option on startup nothing would display but wifi connection). I waited for it to finish and a menu like <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> after option.

My question is what should I do to fix Macintosh HD and make it ready to install OS X? Is there something that must be done with Disk Utility after Internet Recovery to bring back Macintosh HD?
I'm on a MBP 2015

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I think all you need to do is rename the drive using Disk Utility to
MacIntosh HD. Then reinstall to it.

[image]

Comment: just a tip, but you can take a screenshot of a single window or element by tapping the space bar after shift + command + 4.  This results in cleaner screen grabs.  You will notice a camera icon, hover it over the subject you wish to capture. Cheers!

Comment: 'tis a pleasure!

Comment: u see like a 5 6 years old kid Scott!!! @_@

Comment: I see like a 63 year old kid with MS distorting my vision and eyeglasses make it worse.